# dlopen definition of "same library"

Tags: linux, elf, dlopen

According to the [dlopen(3) man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen):

> If the same library is loaded again with dlopen(), the same file handle is returned.

What does "same library" mean? Same filename? Same path? Same inode? Same SONAME? Something else? How does this behavior interact with soft links?

Assume I am interested in ELF so's and mainstream Linux distros (Debian / Arch / RHEL families).

Example consequences:

- If "same library" means "same SONAME" then I could have the same file twice with different names be loaded and only get one handle. If "same library" means "same filename" then I would probably get a horrible mess with colliding symbols.
- If symlinks are followed back to the file and "same library" means "same filename", then multiple symlinks to one file are okay, else if the filename of the symlink is used instead, again things are a horrible mess.
- If "same library" means "same path" and two paths exist to a file (e.g. with hardlinks), things are a mess, else if "same library" means "same inode", all is okay.

Comment: It also says it reference counts, so it shouldn't really matter to you. Can you explain why it makes a difference or if you're trying to ask something more specific?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I gave some examples of the kinds of considerations which caused me to post this question. Does this help you understand what I'm looking for?

Comment: It should be inode, as you can delete and recreate a shared library with the same name, and it will be a different library. (On the other hand, opening an existing shared library for output is either impossible _(text file busy_ error), or causes segfaults in processes that use the library.)

Answer (score 3):

I decided to dig into the musl source for, well, a possible interpretation of the words. The function in question is `load_library()`, at https://github.com/ifduyue/musl/blob/3ab2a4e02682df1382955071919d8aa3c3ec40d4/ldso/dynlink.c#L990.

The "already loaded" search `for (p=head->next; p; p=p->next) if (...) return p;` occurs in two places:

1. First in the non-pathname case, where the name itself is checked for dup againsr a shortname (the shortname is not a soname, rather a basename of the resolved filename like `libfoo.so`)
2. Then in a general path, where the device and inode numbers are searched for dup. The values come from fstat on an fopen'ed handle.

In addition, the shortname is only saved in a nom-path case.

---

The #2 case seems to explicitly merge hard links. The use of fopen also implicitly merges symlinks.

At no point was the ELF file itself ever consulted for sameness. So it's not a horrible mess, but not super smart either.

---

I am way too tired to read glibc right now, but I can't imagine anything unusual there. Node.js's AIX polyfill uses inode too.

Answer (score 1):

I would say *same library means same path*, i have built a small example to illustrate :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    (void)argc, (void)argv;

    void (*hello)();

    void *handle = dlopen("./libhello.so", RTLD_NOW);
    printf("handle = %p\n", handle);

    void *handle2 = dlopen("libs/libhello.so", RTLD_NOW);
    printf("handle with different path = %p\n", handle2);

    // using symlink to libhello.so
    void *handle3 = dlopen("./symlink.so", RTLD_NOW);
    printf("handle with soft link = %p\n", handle3);

    if (handle == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
        exit(1);
    }

    void *f = dlsym(handle, "hello");

    if (f) {
        hello = (void (*)())f;
        hello();
    }

    dlclose(handle);

    return 0;
}
```

and the shared lib :

```
/* libhello.so */
#include <stdio.h>

void hello()
{
    printf("hello\n");
}
```

output is :

```
handle = 0x217c030
handle with different path = 0x217ca40
handle with soft link = 0x217c030
hello
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Your experiment is incomplete. In particular, your test doesn't set `SONAME`, and doing so will change the outcome.

Comment: Actually, i have set the `SONAME` of `libhello.so` to `libhello.so.1` and then copy the lib into another directory so both libs have the same `SONAME` but different path and this leads to different handle. Do you mean that same lib means same soname ?

Comment: I think you really just need to add the shell commands for symlinking and copying to be explicit.